# Uploading data in background iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to upload data to server and it will be great to do it when app is in background. So I've read that I can upload using download task:

> Uploading a File Using a Download Task
>
> To upload body content for a
> download task, your app must provide either an NSData object or a body
> stream as part of the NSURLRequest object provided when it creates the
> download request.

So according to that I implemented simple method:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBodyStream = InputStream(data: data))
URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main).downloadTask(with: request).resume()
```

I works great, but as I said it's good to do it in background, so I changed last line with this:

```
 URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "backgroundSession"), delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main).downloadTask(with: request).resume()
```

And now when I want to resume this task I get response from server with code 400 and message:

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's really impossible in iOS?

Code in Swift or Objective-C will be appreciated.

Comment: No I didn't confused.

Comment: Please see this documentation... https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: I vaguely remember that background uploads only work if you provide a URL to a file, and that you can't do background uploads of an `NSData`/`Data` object. I can't seem to find that bit of the documentation though.